# Why does BLDC shaft magnetic field collapse when commutation occurs

Tags: motor, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I'm watching this video to try to understand motor control,

https://youtu.be/WYJWdMV3YMs?t=420

Here the video says that one of three phases would "collapse" in
its field strength when commutation occurs,

I think this is called Inductive Flyback.

Why does this happen?

Comment: That phase is disconnected from the supply, so the field "collapses", drops to zero.

Comment: Not the one which is disconnected. The one which is still there, after the one gets disconnected.
So for instance BC is on, and you turn off C, B is still on but weakened.("Collapses").
I believe this is what the effect is referring to.

Comment: When C is disconnected, what do you think happens to current entering B?

Comment: I think you might have gotten the labels confused. A is getting disconnected, while C's magnetic field is collapsing, and B is being turned out at the same time. My confusion is to what is the mechanism behind the immediate response from C, as A gets disconnected. Is the response due to a change in how the voltage and current levels, or a magnetic field phenomena? Thanks!